# Best queue for sliding windows in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing sliding windows protocol:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ABC {
    static boolean status_1 = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockingQueue<String> block1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(7); // size 7
        Thread a1 = new Thread(new receive(block1));
        Thread a2 = new Thread(new send(block1));
        a2.start();
        a1.start();
    }
}

class receive implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<String> block;

    public receive(BlockingQueue<String> block) {
        this.block = block;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {

                System.out.println("out: " + block.size() + " " + block.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class send implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<String> block;

    public send(BlockingQueue<String> block) {
        this.block = block;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
        int i = 0;
        String e;
        while (true) {
            try {
                e = "" + i++;
                System.out.println(e);
                block.put(e);
                if (i == 1000) {
                    break; //Test 1000 number
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException f) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

In my example I used `BlockingQueue` to do the task but it delayed alot. The `receive` thread keep full size. 
Is there any queue in `Java` could do the task with better performance in real time UDP?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @NoorNawaz in sliding windows. When the receiver recieved the packet, It will put to stack and check its sequence number. My question is: which stack can put and pop fast for real time UDP

Comment: So stack or queue?

Comment: All stacks can push and pop fast. You have more important things to worry about. The relevance of stacks to sliding-window protocols escapes me.

Comment: @EJP edited question with queue instead of stack. When I use `queue.offer` the `queue` keep full size and ignore alot of packet.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, that you have no guarnatees that "sending" thread will work with the "same speed" as the "receiving" thread. Parralel thread execution is non-deterministic. You assume otherwise.

You have introduced logical synchonization between threads by assumption that both threads will work with the same speed - 1 item put, 1 item taken, 1 item put, 1 item taken and so on.

So by accident this works for you in case of `put` but not with `offer` it is because according to docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html `put` will block until queue will have space to accept new element - that synchronization is missing when u use offer, resuylting in dropped packets.

So basicly what is happening here, is that `sending` thread occupy more CPU time thus production more data than `receiver` can consume resulting in dropped data.

It is not about queue performance at all.

Basicly your code is not the great example as there is no natural network latency etc. This code might work to some point , if we would introduce network latency. You can emulate that by adding `Thread.sleep(ms)` in producer thread between `put` call.

As a side not, stick to [Java's naming convetion](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the messuring method. You use *block.size()* to determine the queue fill grade. The *size()* method is a relatively long running operation on the queue, which leads to the **send** thread running away.

If you remove the size output you will see a quite fairly distributed output between **send** and **receive**.

By the way, using *System.out* also disturbs your experiment because of the synchronization to the console output stream. A better approach would be using independent output streams with some timing information.